# How to show data from firebase database in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, nodes

I want to send user name in the mail but instead of name , a URL of that name is send every time. Here is my code

```
exports.onUserCreated = functions.database.ref('/user/{pushId}/email')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context ) => {
      // Do something when a new user is created
      var email = snapshot.val();

      var name = snapshot.ref.parent.child('name');

      return sendWelcomeEmaill(email, name);
    });


function sendWelcomeEmaill(email, name){
const mailOptions = {

    from :  `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
mailOptions.text = `Hey ${name || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. \n\n We hope you will enjoy our service.`;
return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
  return console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
});
}
```

Here in this line the problem occurs

```
var name = snapshot.ref.parent.child('name');
```

The output should be in text rather than url of name in user

The database be like

```
user
   -h(random pushID)
     |---email: "yostar18888@gmail.com"
     |---name : "manik"
```

Comment: Without seeing what's in your database, it's impossible to say what's gone wrong.  What are all the actual values that you're dealing with here?

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated my answer in last line please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
var name = snapshot.ref.parent.child('name');
```

you actually assign a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) to the variable `name`, since the [`child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child) method returns a Reference.

So you need to query the value at this reference, by doing

```
exports.onUserCreated = functions.database.ref('/user/{pushId}/email')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context ) => {
      // Do something when a new user is created
      var email = snapshot.val();

      var nameRef = snapshot.ref.parent.child('name');  //Note that variable name was changed to nameRef, to be more meaningful

      return nameRef.once('value')
      .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
         return sendWelcomeEmaill(email, dataSnapshot.val());
      });

 });
```

---

In case you set the name and the email of a user **at the same time**, it may be easier to trigger the Cloud Function at the level of the `user` node instead of the level of the `email` one, like:

```
exports.onUserCreated = functions.database.ref('/user/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context ) => {
      // Do something when a new user is created
      var email = snapshot.val().email;
      var name = snapshot.val().name;
      ......
```

Comment: Dear Renaud both of the methods are not working showing this error        Error: No recipients defined
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:605:19)

Comment: Please help with me in second method

Comment: Firstly, could you please confirm that the values of name and email are correct? You can do some console.log() in the Cloud Function code and see the output in the Firebase console.

Comment: Ya sure name and email values are absolultly correct. Otherwise the email with wrong email address will not be send

Comment: I am not sure to understand: you say the mail is correctly sent? How is your `mailTransport` defined/declared? Perhaps you could open a new question with all the details on how you declare mailTransport, what is the line which generates the error; etc...  As a matter of facts, you initial question was about the problem of getting the `name` value.

Comment: Sorry Renaud after deploying again mail is receiving but again the name is not shown up in the email in your second method

Comment: Even I console the name by       console.log(name); but in firebase console it is showing undefined

Comment: So you mean that in the second method the value of name is not set. Have you noticed that in the second method we listen to '/user/{pushId}' and not to '/user/{pushId}/email'?

Comment: Yep dear Renaud I edited the path to '/user/{pushId}'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186543/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-manik).